# Printing a Linked List to existing Text file- Overwriting the File

Tags: c, file-io, linked-list, nodes

Hey everyone so I'm finding it hard to find a way to write a linked list to an existing text file. At the beginning of the program I read in Employees data from a text file and store them in a linked list. The user can then add Employees. At the end of the program the linked list is written to the file updating it for the next time the program loads. Here is what I have so far. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my Code

```html
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define ID_LENGTH 25
#define NAME_LENGTH 25
#define address_LENGTH 25
#define department_LENGTH 25
#define joinDate_LENGTH 25
#define email_LENGTH 30
int mymenu;

//Create employee Structure
typedef struct employee{
 char* ID;
 char* name;
 char* department;
 char* address;
 char* joinDate;
 double salary;
 char* email;
 struct employee *next;
}employee;

//Declare Function Prototypes
int login();
int Menu();
void Add(struct employee *head);
void search(struct employee *head, char*);
void WriteListToFile(employee *head);
void update(struct employee *head, char*);
void outputList();
struct employee* searchForEmployee(char* );
void savetxt(struct employee *head);
employee* new_employee(char*, char*, char*, char*, char*, double, char*);
employee* insert_by_employee(employee*, employee*);
void removeEmployee(char *);
void print_list(employee*); // prints out the LinkedList


employee* head = NULL; 
employee* tail = NULL;
employee* temp = NULL;
employee* current = NULL;


//this stores the employee that comes before the employee that is found by the searchforEmployee
struct employee *empBeforeEmptoDelete = NULL;

int main() {
 int num = 0;


 FILE *in;
 char* ID = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * ID_LENGTH);
 char* name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * NAME_LENGTH);
 char* department = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * department_LENGTH);
 char* address = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * address_LENGTH);
 char* joinDate = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * joinDate_LENGTH);
 double salary = 0;
 char* email = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * email_LENGTH);

 
 if ((in = fopen("Employees.txt", "r")) == NULL) //Did the file successfully open?
 {
  printf("The input file failed to open.\n");
  printf("Program cannot continue. Exiting. . .\n");
  return 1; //Exit Program
 }


 while (!feof(in)) //Check for file end
 {
  //Read first data value to kickstart.
  if (fscanf(in, "%s %s %s %s %s %lf %s", ID, name, department, address, joinDate, &salary, email) == EOF) {
   break;
  }

  employee* hold = new_employee(ID, name, department, address, joinDate, salary, email);
  head = insert_by_employee(head, hold);

 }
 login();
 
}
employee* new_employee(char* id, char* name, char* department, char* address, char* joinDate, double salary, char* email) {

 //Create new employee and malloc space
 employee* new = (employee*)malloc(sizeof(struct employee));
 new->ID = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * ID_LENGTH);
 new->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * NAME_LENGTH);
 new->department = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * department_LENGTH);
 new->address = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * address_LENGTH);
 new->joinDate = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * joinDate_LENGTH);
 new->email = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * email_LENGTH);
 


 //Set data
 strcpy(new->ID, id);
 strcpy(new->name, name);
 strcpy(new->department, department);
 strcpy(new->address, address);
 strcpy(new->joinDate, joinDate);
 new->salary = salary;
 strcpy(new->email, email);
 //Retun a pointer to the node
 return new;

}

//Inserts new node into an alphabetically sorted linked list.
employee* insert_by_employee(employee* head, employee* new)
{
 employee* current = NULL;
 current = head;
 if (current == NULL || strcmp(current->department, new->department) > 0)
 {
  new->next = current;
  return new;
 }
 else {

  while (current->next != NULL && strcmp(current->next->department, new->department) < 0)
  {

   current = current->next;
  }
 }
 new->next = current->next;
 current->next = new;
 return head;

}
struct employee* searchForEmployee(char* id){
 struct employee *empIterator = head;
 char i[] = "Employee ID";
 char n[] = "Name";
 char a[] = "Address";
 char d[] = "Department";
 char jd[] = "Join Date";
 char s[] = "Salary";
 char em[] = "Email";

 while (empIterator != NULL){
  int isEqual = strcmp(empIterator->ID, id);//if the passed in ID is equla to the ID of the node then isEqual will ring true

  if (!isEqual){
  
   printf("Employee Found\n");
   printf("\n\n|%15s | %15s | %15s | %15s | %15s| %15s | %15s|\n", i, n, a, d, jd, s, em);//header formatting
   printf("|%15s | %15s | %15s |%15s | %15s | %15.2lf| %25s\n", empIterator->ID, empIterator->name, empIterator->address, empIterator->department, empIterator->joinDate, empIterator->salary, empIterator->email);
   //printing out the current node which is the desired employee
   printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
   return empIterator;
  }
  empBeforeEmptoDelete = empIterator;

  empIterator = empIterator->next;
 }
 printf("%s was not found\n\n", id);
 return NULL;
}
void print_list(employee* head)
{
 employee* current;
 current = head;
 char i[] = "Employee ID";
 char n[] = "Name";
 char a[] = "Address";
 char d[] = "Department";
 char jd[] = "Join Date";
 char s[] = "Salary";
 char em[] = "Email";
 

 //Header
 printf("\n\n|%15s | %15s | %15s | %15s | %15s| %15s | %15s|\n", i, n, a, d, jd, s, em);
 printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");


 while (current != NULL)
 {
  printf("|%15s | %15s | %15s |%15s | %15s | %15.2lf| %25s\n", current->ID, current->name, current->address, current->department, current->joinDate, current->salary, current->email);
  current = current->next;
 }
 printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
 
 
 return;
}
//login function takes in user input and compares it the 3
//entries in the Login Struct
int login()
{
 char ch;
 char username[7];//holds the username
 char password[7];//holds the password
 int i;

 printf("\nPlease enter your Username: ");
 gets(username);
 printf("\nPlease enter your Password: ");
 for (i = 0; i<4; i++)//loop 4 times
 {
  ch = getch();//get the first character entered for password
  password[i] = ch;//insert it into the password array
  ch = '*';//change the value of ch to '*'
  printf("%c", ch);//print ch which now contains '*' to the screen
 }

 password[i] = '\0';

 struct login{
  char name[7];
  char password[7];

 };
 struct login details[3];
 fflush(stdin);

 FILE *file;
 file = fopen("login.txt", "r");
 if (file == NULL){
  printf("Can not open the file\n");
  exit(-1);
 }
 fflush(stdin);

 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  fscanf(file, "%s %s\n", details[i].name, details[i].password);
 }


 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  if ((strcmp(details[i].name, username) == 0) && (strcmp(details[i].password, password) == 0))
  {
   printf("\nWelcome %s\n", username);
   Menu();
  }
  fflush(stdin);
 }
}
////basic menu function with a switch statement
int Menu()
{
 int menuChoice = 0;
 int Choice = 9;

 while(menuChoice != 8 ){

  printf("\n");
  printf("1. Add\n");
  printf("2. Show\n");
  printf("3. Update\n");
  printf("4. Delete\n"); // Write a Function for this
  printf("5. Departments\n");
  printf("6. Employee Report\n");
  printf("7. \n");
  printf("8. Exit\n\n\n\t\tSELECTION = ");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%d", &Choice);
  fflush(stdin);

  
   switch (Choice)
   {
   case 1:
   {
    Add(head);
    break;
   }
   case 2:
   {
    char text[10];
    printf("Enter the text to search for :");
    scanf("%s", text);
    //search(head, text);
    searchForEmployee(text);
    break;
   }
   case 3:
   {
    char text[10];
    printf("Enter the ID to update for :");
    scanf("%s", text);
    update(head, text);
    break;
   }
   case 4:
   {
    print_list(head);
    char text[10];
    printf("Enter the ID to remove :");
    scanf("%s", text);
    removeEmployee(text);
    print_list(head);
    break;

   }
   case 5:
   {
    print_list(head);
    break;
   }
   case 6:
   {

    break;
   }
   case 7:
   {
    break;
   }
   case 8:
   {
    WriteListToFile(head);
    exit(0);
    break;
   }
   default:
   {
    printf("\nInvalid Selection");
    break;
   }
   }
  }
  system("Pause");
  printf("\n\n\n");
  return 1; //Exit Success
 } 
//my add function which validates the email and start date
void Add()
{
 
 char* ID = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * ID_LENGTH);
 char* name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * NAME_LENGTH);
 char* department = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * department_LENGTH);
 char* address = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * address_LENGTH);
 char* joinDate = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * joinDate_LENGTH);
 char* tempDate = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * joinDate_LENGTH);
 double salary = 0;
 char* email = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * email_LENGTH);
 char temp[25];
 char com[5] = ".com";
 int m, d, y;
 int daysinmonth[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
 int legit = 3;

 printf("\nEnter the ID : ");
 scanf("%s", ID);
 printf("\nEnter the new employee name : ");
 scanf("%s", name);
 printf("\nEnter their address : ");
 scanf("%s", address);
 printf("\nEnter their department : ");
 scanf("%s", department);
 while (legit != 1){
 printf("\nEnter their start date : ");
 scanf("%s", tempDate);
 sscanf(tempDate, "%02d/%02d/%04d", &m, &d, &y);
 //printf("%d%d%d",m,d,y);
 
  // leap year checking, if ok add 29 days to february
  if (y % 400 == 0 || (y % 100 != 0 && y % 4 == 0))
   daysinmonth[1] = 29;

  // days in month checking
  if (m < 13)
  {
   if (d <= daysinmonth[m - 1])
    legit = 1;
  }

  if (legit == 1){
   printf("\nIt is a legitimate date!\n");
   strcpy(joinDate, tempDate);
  }
  else
   printf("\nIt's not a legitimate date!");
 }
 printf("\nEnter their salary : ");
 scanf("%lf", &salary);
 printf("\nEnter their email : ");
 scanf("%s", temp);
 printf(temp);
 //I use strchr to check the input for a single '@'
 //I then use strstr to check for a substring
  while (strchr(temp, '@') == NULL || strstr(temp, com) == NULL)
  {
  printf("\nThe email doesnt contain an @ sign or .com .");
  printf("\nEnter Employee E-Mail: ");
  fflush(stdin);
  gets(temp);
 }
 strcpy(email, temp);
 
 employee* hold = new_employee(ID, name, department, address, joinDate, salary, email);
 head = insert_by_employee(head, hold);
}
//search by ID or name
void search(struct employee *head, char *crit)//This function takes in the head pointer and a character array pointer
{
 int choice;//menu choice tracker

 //arrays to hold the header heads
 char i[] = "Employee ID";
 char n[] = "Name";
 char a[] = "Address";
 char d[] = "Department";
 char jd[] = "Join Date";
 char s[] = "Salary";
 char em[] = "Email";

 //sub menu to filter by ID and Name searches
 printf("\nSearch by ");
 printf("\n1 : ID");
 printf("\n2 : Name\n");
 scanf("%d", &choice);

 //if the user wants to search by ID
 if (choice == 1){
  while (head != NULL)
  {
   //compare the ID to the criteria. If its the same then execute this if
   if ((strcmp(head->ID, crit) == 0))
   {
    //print that we found the employee
    printf("Employee Found\n");
    printf("\n\n|%15s | %15s | %15s | %15s | %15s| %15s | %15s|\n", i, n, a, d, jd, s, em);//header formatting
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("|%15s | %15s | %15s |%15s | %15s | %15.2lf| %25s\n", head->ID, head->name, head->address, head->department, head->joinDate, head->salary, head->email);
    //printing out the current node which is the desired employee
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    return;
   }
   head = head->next;//increments the node until we get to the end of the Linked List
  }
  printf("Employee not found\n");//Else there is no Employee with an ID of the entered criteria
 }
 //if the user wants to search by Name
 else if (choice == 2){
  while (head != NULL)
  {
   //compare the Name to the criteria. If its the same then execute this if
   if ((strcmp(head->name, crit) == 0))
   {
    //print that we found the employee
    printf("Employee Found\n");
    printf("\n\n|%15s | %15s | %15s | %15s | %15s| %15s | %15s|\n", i, n, a, d, jd, s, em);//header formatting
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("|%15s | %15s | %15s |%15s | %15s | %15.2lf| %25s\n", head->ID, head->name, head->address, head->department, head->joinDate, head->salary, head->email);
    //printing out the current node which is the desired employee
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    return;
   }
   head = head->next;//increments the node until we get to the end of the Linked List
  }
  printf("Employee not found\n");//Else there is no Employee with an Name of the entered criteria
 }
 else
  printf("Bad input");//Otherwise the user entered a choice out of the range of our handled input
}
//the update function uses the search function then uses a holder to transfer data and then overwrite it
void update(struct employee *head, char *crit)//This function takes in the head pointer and a character array pointer
{


 //arrays to hold the header heads
 char i[] = "Employee ID";
 char n[] = "Name";
 char a[] = "Address";
 char d[] = "Department";
 char jd[] = "Join Date";
 char s[] = "Salary";
 char em[] = "Email";

 char id[25];
 char name[25];
 char address[25];
 char department[25];
 char joinDate[25];
 double salary;
 char email[25];

 
 //if the user wants to search by ID
  while (head != NULL)
  {
   //compare the ID to the criteria. If its the same then execute this if
   if ((strcmp(head->ID, crit) == 0))
   {
    //print that we found the employee
    printf("Employee Found\n");
    printf("\n\n|%15s | %15s | %15s | %15s | %15s| %15s | %15s|\n", i, n, a, d, jd, s, em);//header formatting
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("|%15s | %15s | %15s |%15s | %15s | %15.2lf| %25s\n", head->ID, head->name, head->address, head->department, head->joinDate, head->salary, head->email);
    //printing out the current node which is the desired employee
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    printf("\nEnter the ID : ");
    scanf("%s", id);
    printf("\nEnter the new employee name : ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("\nEnter their address : ");
    scanf("%s", address);
    printf("\nEnter their department : ");
    scanf("%s", department);
    printf("\nEnter their start date : ");
    scanf("%s", joinDate);
    printf("\nEnter their salary : ");
    scanf("%lf", &salary);
    printf("\nEnter their email : ");
    scanf("%s", email);

    strcpy(head->ID, id);
    strcpy(head->name, name);
    strcpy(head->department, department);
    strcpy(head->address, address);
    strcpy(head->joinDate, joinDate);
    head->salary = salary;
    strcpy(head->email, email);

    printf("Employee Found\n");
    printf("\n\n|%15s | %15s | %15s | %15s | %15s| %15s | %15s|\n", i, n, a, d, jd, s, em);//header formatting
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("|%15s | %15s | %15s |%15s | %15s | %15.2lf| %25s\n", head->ID, head->name, head->address, head->department, head->joinDate, head->salary, head->email);
    //printing out the current node which is the desired employee
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    return;
   }
   head = head->next;//increments the node until we get to the end of the Linked List
  }
  printf("Employee not found\n");//Else there is no Employee with an ID of the entered criteria
 }
//this was a secondary function to output the LinkedList. Not the one used in finished solution
void outputList(){
 //this was a secondary function to output the LinkedList. Not the one used in finished solution
 char i[] = "Employee ID";
 char n[] = "Name";
 char a[] = "Address";
 char d[] = "Department";
 char jd[] = "Join Date";
 char s[] = "Salary";
 char em[] = "Email";

 struct employee * employees = head;
 printf("Employees Entered\n\n");
 while (employees != NULL){
  printf("Employee Found\n");
  printf("\n\n|%15s | %15s | %15s | %15s | %15s| %15s | %15s|\n", i, n, a, d, jd, s, em);//header formatting
  printf("|%15s | %15s | %15s |%15s | %15s | %15.2lf| %25s\n", employees->ID, employees->name, employees->address, employees->department, employees->joinDate, employees->salary, employees->email);
  printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

  employees = employees->next;
 }
}//this was a secondary function to output the LinkedList. Not the one used in finished solution
//my remove employee function
void removeEmployee(char* empID){

 struct employee* empToDelete = NULL;//this holds the employee we are deleting

 empToDelete = searchForEmployee(empID);//we use the search function we made to get the employees details

 if (empToDelete != NULL){//if we find him execute this for

  printf("%s was deleted\n\n", empID);//let the user know the employee details ahve been deleted

  if (empToDelete == head){

   head = empToDelete->next;
  }
  else{
   empBeforeEmptoDelete->next = empToDelete->next;
  }

  free(empToDelete);//Delete the details from memory
 }
 else//otherwise the employee was not found
 {
  printf("%s was not found", empID);
 }
}
void savetxt(struct employee *head)
{
 FILE *f;
 f = fopen("Employees.txt", "w+");
 if (f == NULL)
 {
  printf("error");
 }
 //struct employee *Current = head->next;
 while (head != NULL)
 {
  
  fprintf(f, "%s\n", head->ID);
  fprintf(f, "%s\n", head->name);
  fprintf(f, "%s\n", head->address);
  fprintf(f, "%s\n", head->department);
  fprintf(f, "%s\n", head->joinDate);
  fprintf(f, "%lf\n", head->salary);
  fprintf(f, "%s\n", head->email);
  head = head->next;
 }
  //head = head->next;
  fprintf(f, "\n\n");
 
 fclose(f);
 return NULL;
}

void WriteListToFile(employee *head) {
 FILE *pFile;
 pFile = fopen("Employees.txt", "w");

 if (pFile != NULL) {
  employee *currentEmp = head;

  employee *holdNext = NULL;
  

  while (currentEmp != NULL) {
   holdNext = currentEmp->next;
   
   currentEmp->next = NULL;

   fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
   fprintf(currentEmp, sizeof(employee), 1, pFile);

   printf("Writing:%s to file\n", currentEmp->name);

   currentEmp->next = holdNext;

   holdNext = NULL;
   currentEmp = currentEmp->next;
  }
  fclose(pFile);
  pFile = NULL;
 }
 else {
  printf("FILE OPEN ERROR\n");
 }

}
```

here is the employee text file

```html
EMP1 Martin Computer Clare 06/06/1996 60000 martinemp@gmail.com
EMP2 John Accounting Galway 05/05/1995 50000 johnemp@gmail.com
EMP3 Kevin Computer Kilkenny 04/04/1994 34000 kevinemp@gmail.com
EMP4 Kim Sales Sligo  03/03/1993 65000 kimemp@gmail.com
EMP5 Keith Accounting Ballina 02/02/1992 53200 keithemp@gmail.com
EMP6 Tim Sales Dublin 01/01/1991 23000 timemp@gmail.com
EMP7 Andy Computer Chicago 07/07/1990 10000 andyemp@gmail.com
```

Here is the login info

```html
martin 1234
tim 5678
keith 4321
```

Comment: What's the issue that you see?

Comment: Hey basically the file is empty when the program ends.

Comment: So perhaps the linked list is empty? Do you see the "try" line on the stdout? Also the fields might be empty strings. Print them as well.

Comment: I have a function to print the linked list out to screen. It's not empty

Comment: if you change all of the `fprintf`s to `printf` to `stdout`, is it printing?

Comment: what's the purpose of `struct employee *Current = head->next` ?

Comment: It was just something i added in in a desperate attempt to get it to work.

Comment: I have a function that prints the Linked List. I run that function after I read in the data from file and after I add a new employee. The Linked List is populated at the time the program ends at which point this method tries to print the linked list to file. For some reason the file is blank when the program ends.

Comment: I guess you will have to provide more code. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I just uploaded the complete project

Answer (score 0):

Edit 1:

The issue seems to be here:

```
if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("error");
}
```

Even though you are testing for NULL, you are not exiting the method immediately.

```
if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("error");
    return;
}
```

Initial suggestion (ignore for now):

Can you try after removing the next `head` move. It should be throwing an error.

```html
void savetxt(struct employee *head)
{
 FILE *f;
 f = fopen("Employees.txt", "w+");
 if (f == NULL)
 {
  printf("error");
 }
 struct employee *Current = head->next;
 while (head != NULL)
 {
  
  printf("try");
  fprintf(f, "%s\n", head->ID);
  fprintf(f, "%s\n", head->name);
  fprintf(f, "%s\n", head->address);
  fprintf(f, "%s\n", head->department);
  fprintf(f, "%s\n", head->joinDate);
  fprintf(f, "%lf\n", head->salary);
  fprintf(f, "%s\n", head->email);
  head = head->next;
 }
  /* head = head->next; */
  fprintf(f, "\n\n");
 
 fclose(f);
 return NULL;
}
```

Comment: First-chance exception at 0x7706CC70 (ntdll.dll) in LinkedList.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified. It throws me this error.